# Why spark1.5.0 ml ann can't be used

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

When I used the spark ml 1.5.0, I find ann. Here is my problem.

1. spark website not describe the ann and api.
2. the ann package is private

   e.g.

   ```
    private[ml] object FeedForwardTopology
   ```
3. can I use it in my project?
   4.how?

Comment: Because the code of ann is constantly evolving and Spark is aiming for API stability. 
You can extend and then make public the private components.

Comment: how can i extend the priv components,copy source code?